# Cohomological dimension of truncated algebraic De Rham complex.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

Is true that the cohomological dimension of the (fine) truncated algebraic De Rham complex $\tau^{\leq q}\Omega^{\bullet}$ is at most $2q$? i.e. its sheaf cohomology vanishes above $2q$. If necessary you can assume we are working on a smooth projective complex variety.